# How to detect a turning point of a graph with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an exponential decay like graph of x and y values with a turning point marked in a diagram below. My question is, with or without the noises, how can I detect the region or the middle point of the turning point using Python? The values are in csv file given in this [link](http://www.filedropper.com/phish1_2).

UPDATES: This is more clearer diagram showing the turning/changing point.

[image]

Comment: Can you, please, clarify what's "turning point" exactly? Can you give an mathematical definition of it? It will help a lot. Also it's very hard to see what's going on with data on the graph you have attached. Please, show as that "turning point" as clear as you can.

Comment: @Hett I refer a turning point here as a bending of the graph roughly between 3 and 10 values of X, ignoring the noises. Unfortunately, I do not have any mathematical formula to back up the pattern but possibly the attached data can give you a picture.

Comment: did you try anything? what about calculating a gradient using [numpy.gradient](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) and setting a threshold value? you might have to apply some sort of smoothing kernel to get rid of the noise though...

Comment: @MrFuppes I am a newbie in Python, so demonstrating codes will be helpful to begin with

Answer (score 2):

a simple way to approach this could be to use `np.gradient` and a threshold value.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# generate some toy data
n = 600
t = np.linspace(0, 600, n)
y = (300 * np.exp(-0.1 * t) + 1) + 20 * (np.random.random(n))

# get the gradient
dy = np.gradient(y)

# search gradient for first occurrence of thresh value:
thresh = 0.01
idx_thresh = np.argmax(dy > thresh)
# y[idx_thresh] would be the "turning point"

# visualization
plt.plot(t, y, 'b', label='y')
plt.plot(t, dy, 'g', label='dy')
plt.plot(t[idx_thresh:], y[idx_thresh:], 'r', label=f'y[dy > {thresh}]')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

**However**, where the threshold value is found will pretty much depend on the noise! So you will likely have to do some smoothing, e.g.

```py
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

y_filtered = savgol_filter(y, 11, 3)
dy_f = np.gradient(y_filtered)
idx_thresh = np.argmax(dy_f > thresh)

plt.plot(t, y_filtered, 'k', label='y_filtered')
plt.plot(t, dy_f, 'g', label='dy_f')
plt.plot(t[idx_thresh:], y[idx_thresh:], 'r', label=f'y[dy > {thresh}]')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Note that the gradient is now much smoother. **Important:** it depends on the input data which filter is appropriate!

Comment: Thanks for your codes. Its not clear yet, which value/variable stand for the turning point?

Comment: I've added a comment in the first code section. `idx_thresh` marks the index of the "turning point" as it is where `dy` (something similar to the first derivative, just not in a mathematical sense) is greater than the threshold `thresh`. maybe play around with the parameters a bit to get a feeling ;-)